# Truck and packet problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Ten trucks, numbered 1 to 10 , are carrying packets of sugar. Each packet weighs either
 999 g  or 1000 g and each truck carries only the packets of equal weights.  The combined weight of 1 packet selected from the first truck, 2 packets from the second, 4 packet from the third and so on and 2^9  packets from the tenth truck is 1022870 g.  The trucks that have the lighter bags are:

---

a)1,3,5

---

b)2,4,5

---

c)1,9

---

d)2,8

How to solve this problem and what is the basic idea between solving these types of problems?

Comment: Where did you find this problem? What have you tried?

Comment: Are you familiar with binary numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:  what is the total number of packets that were weighed?  Call it $n$ Now deduct $999$g from each packet and $999n$g from the total weight-the packets that used to weigh $999$ now weigh zero and the ones that used to weigh $1000$ now weigh $1$, so the remaining weight is the number of original $1000$g packets.  Now express the remaining weight in binary-why?

Comment: I'm not much used to solving these types of problems so, please elaborate.

Comment: You haven't indicated if you know anything about binary numbers, for example that $1+2+2^2+\dots2^n=2^{n+1}-1$, so I don't know where to start.  Did you do the calculation I suggested?  What did you get?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know about it......sorry for the late information..

Comment: You might look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number  You are trying to express the number left in binary, with each one bit representing a truck that has the heavy bags.